# Add system config file in Customers Tab in Stores -> Configuration

Tags: magento2

I have created a module in Magento 2 and want to show it config file in Customers Tab in Stores -> Configuration section.

What I have to give in system.xml file to show in that default section.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <section id="trade_customer" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="100" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
            <label>Trade Customer</label>
            <tab>customer</tab>
            <group id="general" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>General Configuration</label>
                <field id="enable" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Module Enable</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
                </field>
            </group>
        </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

Comment: Can you add your system.xml to your question?

Comment: Your question is not clear. What you exactly need, new section tab, new group under existing section tab or only need to add few fields under any existing group? Please specify

Comment: @SukumarGorai I have added

Comment: @HirenBhalodiya I have to add my module system config under Customers Tab in Stores -> Configuration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below code:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <section id="trade_customer" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="100" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
            <class>separator-top</class>
            <label>Trade Customer</label>
            <tab>customer</tab>
            <resource>Magento_Customer::config_customer</resource>
            <group id="general" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>General Configuration</label>
                <field id="enable" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Module Enable</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
                </field>
            </group>
        </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

Comment: Welcome. Happy Coding.