# Magento 2 Adminhtml add a custom table

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, menu

I want to add a table here
[image]

Like the one in customer -> edit. I figured out how to create it (in system.xml):

```
<system>
<tab id="example_tab" sortOrder="10">
    <label>MYModule</label>
</tab>

<section id="example_section" translate="label" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
    <label>Example config section</label>
    <tab>example_tab</tab>

    <resource>MYModule_SendCoupon::config</resource>

    <group id="general" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
        <label>Partner Informations</label>

        <field id="name" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
            <label>Name</label>
            <validate>required-entry validate-number</validate>
        </field>

    </group>

</section>
```

This is what I want

[image]

Comment: check this link --- https://www.rakeshjesadiya.com/create-tab-in-admin-customer-edit-page-in-magento-2/

Comment: Very helpful, thank you, but what if I want to create a new table different from the customer's one?

Comment: Please add screenshot. So I understand you what want to.

Comment: In your tutorial I add a new option for the "Customer Information" table, I want to add a brand new table for my custom layout, for example I go to url/admin/a/b/rbj and there is a table named "Rbj Informations" with the options "Rbj View", "Rbj Account Informations", etc..

Comment: Okay.You means `Customer Information` is label right.And in `Customer Information` add columns like `Rbj Informations ,Rbj View,Rbj Account Informations`. ???

Comment: I posted a screenshot in a new answer

Comment: you try to using system.xml file.check this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/240381/add-system-config-file-in-customers-tab-in-stores-configuration